# why iPhone video shot @ 1080p 30fps has a resolution of only 720x1280?

Tags: iphone, video, resolution

The videos are shot on iPhone 5S and iPhone 6S in portrait mode. I've checked the Camera setting and it is set to record video at 1080p at 30fps. But when downloaded onto a computer, the videos are shown to have resolution at 720x1280 (with NO change to resolution). I was under the impression that 1080p is FHD (so 1080x1920), and not 720x1280. I feel like this is something very simple that I'm just missing somehow.

In comparison, when shooting video (also in portrait) using Samsung Galaxy s9, also with the camera setting at FHD 1080p at 30 fps, the downloaded video remains at this resolution (1080x1920).

PS: the set up is a bit hard to explain, but essentially I'm testing a video API so the video is taken on the phone, within Safari (for the iPhones, and Chrome for Galaxy), and directly pushed over wifi to my storage. Yes there's also transcoding from .mov to .mp4, BUT the resolution should not have changed (and in fact didn't change when the video is from Samsung Galaxy s9). And yes, the iOS is up to date. Also I've now tested this when the video is taken in landscape form. makes no difference. (except 720x1280 is now 1280x720)

Comment: If no one steps up, perhaps edit this to explain the steps and software involved for the download to the computer. On macOS the photos app and finder bring in full images assuming the MacOS is recent and patched up to date.

Comment: @bmike thanks, I've just added some more info.

Comment: Excellent. Using Linux or Mac or Windows or another os? USB or Bluetooth or WiFi? I think you’re so familiar with your setup you might miss that we don’t know what you’re doing. For all we know you email them to the computer.

Comment: Do I understand your PS correctly: You are accessing the camera software in your phone indirectly via an app/extension/API/handler/whatever in Safari? So it's User <==>Safari<==>API<==>camera?